# Python Dictionary as tuple keys not increasing the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I've a list of list for example `transactions = [['1','2','3','4','5','6'],['2','3','6','1','5','10],['6','4','5','6','4','3']]`
and a Dict with tuples as keys for example `triplets = {(1,2,3): 0, (2,3,4):0}`
now i want to check if the keys of `triplets` are occurred in the transactions as (1,2,3) is in first nested list then I'll update the values of that key tuple ( It will become 1 from 0). if it is found in another list e.g. it is also available in the second list **`[2,3,6,1,5,10]`** then It's count will increase from 1 to 2. And this process will go on for the whole **triplets**.

I wrote this code but it's not increasing the count.

```
    for items in triplets.keys():
        if items in transactions:
            triplets[items] = triplets[items] + 1
```

if someone can edit the question title properly please. I can't find the right words to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition always evaluates to being False.

Think this is what you are looking for,

```
for items in triplets.keys():
    for transaction in transactions:
        if all(x in map(int,transaction) for x in items): #python 2
        #if all(x in list(map(int,transaction)) for x in items): #python 2 and 3
            triplets[items] = triplets[items]+1
```

Output:

```
{(2, 3, 4): 1, (1, 2, 3): 2}
```

Edit based on change in question

Comment: If is still false all the time.

Comment: kindly check the question again. the values in transactions are string format and values in triplets are integers.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You could use `set` to check intersection of the each of `keys` of `triplets` and the elements of the `sub-lists` of `transactions`. If the intersection yields the same result as the `key`, then increase the count for that `key` in `triplets` dictionary.

```py
transactions = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,6,1,5,10],[6,4,5,6,4,3]]
transactions = [[str(e) for e in ee] for ee in transactions]
print('transactions: {}'.format(transactions))
triplets = {(1,2,3): 0, (2,3,4):0}
print('triplets: ')
print('\tBefore Update: {}'.format(triplets))

for key in triplets.keys():
    count = triplets.get(key)
    for t in transactions:
        s = set(list(key))
        count += int(set(t).intersection(s) == s)
    triplets.update({key: count})

print('\tAfter Update: {}'.format(triplets))
```

**Output**:

```
transactions: [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['2', '3', '6', '1', '5', '10'], ['6', '4', '5', '6', '4', '3']]
triplets: 
    Before Update: {(1, 2, 3): 0, (2, 3, 4): 0}
    After Update: {(1, 2, 3): 0, (2, 3, 4): 0}
```

Comment: kindly check the question again. the values in transactions are string format and values in triplets are integers.

Comment: how to check or integer with string?
or first I've to convert integers to strings as well.

Comment: Ok. Will update the solution accordingly. Thank you for pointing it out. Although this should not change the basic solution.

Comment: You don't need to change anything. Just apply the **`for loop`** **as-is**.